# An interpretation of $ \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} $.

Tags: differential-geometry, soft-question, differential-forms, smooth-manifolds

$ \left( \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} \right)_{p} $ is both an element of the tangent space $ {T_{p}}(M) $ and a linear functional on $ {C^{1}}(M) $, while $ (\mathrm{d}{x})_{p} $ is an element of the cotangent space $ {T^{*}_{p}}(M) $.

> **Question.** How should I interpret $ \dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{2}} $, or more generally, higher-order partial derivatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ (M,\mathcal{A}) $ be an $ n $-dimensional $ C^{\infty} $-manifold, meaning that $ M $ is a topological space and $ \mathcal{A} $ is a set of ordered pairs $ (U,\phi) $, where $ U $ is an open subset of $ M $ and $ \phi: U \to \Bbb{R}^{n} $ is a topological embedding, such that $ \displaystyle M = \bigcup_{(U,\phi) \in \mathcal{A}} U $ and for $ (U,\phi),(V,\psi) \in \mathcal{A} $ with $ U \cap V \neq \varnothing $, the map
$$
\psi \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi[U \cap V] \to \psi[U \cap V]
$$
is a $ C^{\infty} $-diffeomorphism between non-empty open subsets of $ \Bbb{R}^{n} $.

**Note:** We call $ \mathcal{A} $ an **atlas** and each element of $ \mathcal{A} $ a **coordinate chart**.

Next, a function $ f: M \to \Bbb{R} $ is called $ C^{\infty} $ if and only if for each $ (U,\phi) \in \mathcal{A} $, $ f \circ \phi^{-1}: \phi[U] \to \Bbb{R} $ is a $ C^{\infty} $-function from an open subset of $ \Bbb{R}^{n} $ to $ \Bbb{R} $.

For a fixed $ (U,\phi) \in \mathcal{A} $, write $ \phi $ in component form: $ \phi = (x_{1},\ldots,x_{n}) $. Hence, $ x_{i} $ is a map from $ U $ to $ \Bbb{R} $ for each $ i \in [n] $. For each $ C^{\infty} $-function $ f: M \to \Bbb{R} $ and each multi-index $ \mu $, we define a function $ \dfrac{\partial^{\mu} f}{\partial x^{\mu}}: U \to \Bbb{R} $ by
$$
\forall p \in U: \quad
\frac{\partial^{\mu} f}{\partial x^{\mu}} (p) \stackrel{\text{df}}{=}
\left[ \mathbf{D}^{\mu} \! \left( f \circ \phi^{-1} \right) \right] \! (\phi(p)).
$$
Hence, the ‘higher derivatives’ of $ f $ depend on the coordinate chart that you are using.

Comment: I know it. For ex. if ${x_{\alpha}^i},{x_{\beta}^i}$ to set of coordinates. We can write $\frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\beta}^j} = \frac{\partial x_{\alpha}^i}{\partial x_{\beta}^j} \frac{\partial}{\partial x_{\alpha}^i}$. 
And i want get similar formula. So since i know that $dx_i$ is element of cotangent space and $d^2$ is bilinear form on tangent space(d^k is k-linear), i can write $d^2f = df \otimes df = (\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}dx\otimes dx + \dots)$. And i want similar interpretation for higher derivatives.
I'm sorry if that question is so stupid and i'm sorry for my eng;)

Comment: So $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \otimes \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \in T_pM\otimes T_pM$?

Comment: @user2715119: Hi user. I want to take back my earlier comments. Observe that $ \dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{i} \partial x^{j}} \Bigg|_{p} $ and $ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}} \Bigg|_{p} \otimes \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}} \Bigg|_{p} $ are two different objects. In order for the first object to make sense, we require $ M $ to be at least a $ C^{2} $-manifold. It is then a linear functional on $ {C^{2}}(M) $, and my answer explains why. The second object is an element of $ {T_{p}}(M) \otimes {T_{p}}(M) $, and it only requires $ M $ to be a $ C^{1} $-manifold to make sense.

Comment: In summary, $ \dfrac{\partial^{2}}{\partial x^{i} \partial x^{j}} \Bigg|_{p} $ is a linear functional on $ {C^{2}}(M) $ and requires $ M $ to be a $ C^{2} $-manifold, whereas $ \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{i}} \Bigg|_{p} \otimes \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x^{j}} \Bigg|_{p} $ is a linear functional on $ {T^{\ast}_{p}}(M) \otimes {T^{\ast}_{p}}(M) $ and only requires $ M $ to be a $ C^{1} $-manifold.